# Redirect with .htaccess but getting old URL as parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, apache2

I want to create a .htaccess file which redirects me from

`https://example.net/@UserName` to `https://example.net/user/index.php?user=UserName`, but only when there is the `@`.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/?$ https://example.net/user/index.php?user=$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect a URL of the form `example.com/@foobar` to `https://example.net/user/index.php?user=foobar` changing the URL in browser address bar. However, if you do not want the URL to change,  use the following instead

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/?$ /user/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. :)